# How to collection tow numbers in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Example:

```
var x=1.5;
var y=1.5;
var r=x+y;
```

Must be result is 3 but the result give me 2

Here is my full code:

```
$("#TxtProgremPrice,#TxtAdditionalPrice").keyup(function () {
    var x=parseInt($("#TxtProgremPrice").val());
    var y = parseInt($("#TxtAdditionalPrice").val());
    if ($("#TxtProgremPrice").val() == "") {
        x = 0;
    }
    if ($("#TxtAdditionalPrice").val() == "") {
        y = 0;
    }
    var r = x + y;
    $("#TxtTotalPrice").val(r);
});
```

Comment: How are you displaying the result ? Can you make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to make your problem clearer ?

Comment: I get 3: http://jsfiddle.net/hjft8/.

Comment: $("#TxtTotalPrice").val(r);

Comment: Please put in more code.. Your html and Jquery..

Comment: result in textbox is 2

Comment: As you could see, the code you posted first gave the expected result. Always post the relevant part of your actual code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use parseInt, you're adding `1+1`, which makes `2`.

Use [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) instead.

Comment: good,result is 3,thank u

Comment: Note that using the [debugger](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/scripts) would have let you see the real values of x and y. So you could have better located the error.